# Where can I ask a question about finding command-line SQL formatters?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I am looking for a command line SQL formatter = SQL prettifier = SQL beautifier (not an online formatter) for Mac. The goal is to run it on the command line and also inside the editor ([Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)) for SQL files under a few thousand lines.

**Which Stack Exchange site is a good choice to ask a question about it?**

I think it is **off-topic** on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) and [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

It is probably **on-topic** on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

**SEE ALSO:**

Most of these questions are closed:

- [What Free SQL Formatting Tools exist? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310188/what-free-sql-formatting-tools-exist)
- [plsql - Good free offline PL/SQL formatter - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522040/good-free-offline-pl-sql-formatter)
- [sql server - Tidy for SQL - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093106/tidy-for-sql)
- [linux - SQL string formatter - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392001/sql-string-formatter)
- [python - How to pretty format the printing of SQL Queries in SQLAlchemy? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335158/how-to-pretty-format-the-printing-of-sql-queries-in-sqlalchemy)
- [postgresql - SQL Query Formatter - Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/sql-query-formatter)
- [database - Linux CLI tool for auto-formatting (pretty printing) large SQL files - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82791/linux-cli-tool-for-auto-formatting-pretty-printing-large-sql-files/82793#82793)

Comment: The last link in your question suggests it's already been asked on Software Recommendations a while ago. It hasn't been closed. While that doesn't guarantee it's on-topic, is there any reason for you to doubt this would be the best place for it?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer and comment on the question! I ended up posting the question on Software Recommendations Stack Exchange: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85348/command-line-sql-formatter-or-beautifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's on topic on both Software Recommendations and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation?tab=Newest) (the Apple site). For best results, use the [Software Recommendations FAQ about how to ask](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336) (or the [version adapted for Ask Different](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/183281)).

Etiquette says you should only post on one site.

Also, you are correct. This type of question would *not* be accepted on Stack Overflow or [DBA](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/987).

Answer (score -4):

Stack Exchange for "[Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)" is the right place,

But!

"[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)" is the best place.

Comment: Not  necessarily - software recommendations are a special, slightly sensitive case and nearly every site disallows them

Comment: The proposed question would absolutely be off-topic for Stack Overflow.